# Django: define a name for reverse ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_field = ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bar_field = ...
```

and I can access all Bar instances related to a Foo with:

```
Foo.bar_set.all()
```

Is there a way to change the 'reverse name', like in ManyToManyField, so that I can write:

```
Foo.bars.all()
```

?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

yes, using [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_field = ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name="bars", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bar_field = ...
```

Comment: ...personnaly I wouldn't recommend this solution. You will have name of one reverse FK w/o `_set` in its name but others FKs left intact? It's a bit inconsistent. What happens when you later add column named `bars`? Or wouldn't be better to add @property `bars` which returns 'self.bar_set.all()' ?