# Does django model support multiple slug?

Tags: python, django-3.0

Learning django for the first time. Want to generate a url like this - example.com/category,pk,title

Currently i can only generate this - example.com/pk,title

Here is my models.py

```
class ArticlePkAndSlug(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (('Offer', 'Offer'),('Archive', 'Archive'),)
title = models.CharField(max_length=settings.BLOG_TITLE_MAX_LENGTH)
status = models.CharField(max_length=settings.BLOG_TITLE_MAX_LENGTH,null = True,blank=True,choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
#description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
slug0 = models.SlugField(
    default="", editable=False, max_length=settings.BLOG_TITLE_MAX_LENGTH
)
slug1 = models.SlugField(
    default="", editable=False, max_length=settings.BLOG_TITLE_MAX_LENGTH
)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    #kwargs = { "pk": self.id, "slug": self.slug}
    kwargs = {"slug0": self.slug0, "pk": self.id, "slug1": self.slug1}
    return reverse("article-pk-slug-detail", kwargs=kwargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    status = self.status
    title = self.title.replace(" ", "_")
    self.slug0 = slugify(status,allow_unicode=True)
    self.slug1 = slugify(title,allow_unicode=True)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
path(
    "<str:slug0>,<int:pk>,<str:slug1>",
    ArticlePkAndSlugDetailView.as_view(),
    name="article-pk-slug-detail",
),
```

And i get this scope to learn something new:

```
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /django- blog/
    Exception Value: Reverse for 'article-pk-slug-detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug0': 'offer', 'pk': 4, 'slug1': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['supercar\\/(?P<slug0>[^/]+)\\,(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\,(?P<slug1>[^/]+)$']
```

What noob thing i have tried? Help me!

Comment: Did you try a `related_name`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8103897/893159

Comment: What if i remove keep only articlepkandslug model?